# trouble encoding a window.location.href

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

The following is redirecting with spaces in the URL, which I'm trying to remove with encodeURIComponent.

Can anyone show me what I am doing wrong?

Edit: per suggestion below, I'm posting the entire script...

```
<script>        
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId   : '<?php echo $AppID; ?>',
        oauth   : true,
        status  : true, // check login status
        cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
    });

  };

function fb_login(){
    FB.login(function(response) {

        if (response.authResponse) {

            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                //Ajax Loader       
                     $.post("addtodb.php",
                     {name: response.name, email:response.email},
                        function(data) {
                        window.location.href = "next.php?name="+escape(response.name)+"&email="+(response.email); //redirect after post callback
                     })
            });

        } else {
        }
    }, {
        scope: 'email'
    }
    );
}
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Comment: Try using `escape`in stead of `encodeURIComponent`

Answer (score 2):

```
escape('foo bar');//foo%20bar
encodeURI('foo bar');//foo%20bar
encodeURIComponent('foo bar');//foo%20bar
```

These three examples work well. If the don't, then check fi there's nothing else on code that's causing an error or post the whole script here

Comment: Thanks, not sure what the issue is. I updated the OP with the entire script.

Comment: Could you post the content(s) of the 'response' var?

Comment: It's coming from Facebook's API, but the output is "Firstname Lastname"

Comment: Well, so please post `"next.php?name="+escape(response.name)+"&email="+(response.email)` evaluated

Comment: Try this code: `window.location.replace("next.php?name="+escape(response.name)+"&email="+(response.email));`

Comment: Tried that, without luck. Not sure why I didn't check this sooner, but escape and encodeURIComponent works in Chrome and IE. Not in FF.  When you ask to post the contents of the 'response' var, are you asking for this?  `http://www.mysite.com/next.php?name=My Name&email=my@email.com`

Comment: Now other test: Try this code `window.location.replace("next.php?name="+escape(escape(response.name))+"&email="+(respo‌​nse.email));`